# Swift use of unresolved identifier `create` in RxSwift

Tags: swift, macos, rx-swift

I'm starting to learn Swift and I'm implementing an Observable (using RxSwift) to simplify Network calls via AlamoFire in an OSX app.

Imports:

```
import RxSwift
import RxCocoa
import Alamofire
```

Method:

The create identifier below is reporting:
**Use of unresolved identifier `create`**

```
func getAPI(body: String) -> Observable<AnyObject?> {
    return create { observer in
        let request = AlamoFireXMLPostRequest(body)
            .responseData(completionHandler: { request, response, data, error in
                if ((error) != nil) {
                    observer.on(.Error(error!))
                } else {
                    observer.on(.Next(getXMLfromFreshbooksResponse(response)))
                    observer.on(.Completed)
                }
            })
        return AnonymousDisposable {
            request.cancel()
        }
    }
}
```

CocoaPods:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'
# Needed by SWXMLHash
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :osx, '10.10'

target 'Tractor Beam' do
  # Comment this line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for Tractor Beam
  pod 'Alamofire', '~> 3.4'

  # Convert HTTP AF Responses to XML    
  pod 'AlamofireXmlToObjects'
  pod 'SWXMLHash', '~> 2.5.0'

  # Rx
  pod 'RxSwift', '~> 2.6.0'
  pod 'RxCocoa', '~> 2.6.0'

  target 'Tractor BeamTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  target 'Tractor BeamUITests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end

#post_install do |installer|
#    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
#        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
#            config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '3.0'
#            config.build_settings['MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '10.10'
#        end
#    end
#end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`create` is a static method on the `Observable` class. As such, you need to call it by, for e.g.: `Observable.create`...

Also, you should avoid gratuitous use of the `!` operator. So for example:

```
if ((error) != nil) {
    observer.on(.Error(error!))
}
```

Should be written:

```
if let error = error {
    observe.on(.Error(error))
}
```